# Check if parameter is null or emptry string in WHERE query postgresql

Tags: postgresql, apache-nifi

I have a table in PostgreSQL that I'm querying via parameters from Apache Nifi. This query can be passed valid uuids or empty strings via parameters.

I can't work out how to check and then convert these empty strings to NULL. This query works fine if it's passed NULLs:

```
SELECT timestamp,
       data_uuid
FROM data d
WHERE (? IS NULL or d.process_uuid = CAST(? AS uuid));
```

This does not work if it's passed empty strings as it always attempts to query using the empty string:

```
SELECT timestamp,
       data_uuid
FROM data d
WHERE (? ='' or d.process_uuid = CAST(? AS uuid));
```

Comment: maybe with WHERE ( coalesce( ?, '') = '' or d.process_uuid = CAST(? AS uuid)); coalesce return the first not null in a serie, now if null or '' is the same to compre

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Frank that works in Apache Nifi fine.

```
SELECT timestamp,
       data_uuid
FROM data d
WHERE ( coalesce( ?, '') = '' or d.process_uuid = CAST(? AS uuid));
```

If anyone else uses DataGrip and then trys to pass an empty string using '' as a parameter this query will fail:

[DataGrip parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lN4KP.png)

It requires null instead:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000374164-Parameters-with-null-value